# Atributo de valor máximo a un input number con un valor de respuesta de ajax

Tags: mysql, ajax, input-type, data-atributos

Tengo una ventana modal que carga unos valores a través de una consulta usando ajax, en este modal le estoy colocando un input number y el cual deseo que el valor máximo sea un dato que he obtenido en mi consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo si el valor de lo que esta pendiente de entregar es 2, quiero que mi input number como máximo llegue hasta 2. Espero haberme explicado bien.

Este es el Ajax que utilizo:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
    var user_id = $(this).attr("id_pendiente");
    $.ajax({
        url:"paginador/retornarfetch_single.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{user_id:user_id},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#userModal').modal('show');
            $('#dni').val(data.dni);
            $('#descripcion').val(data.descripcion); 
            $('#cantidad').val(data.cantidad);                            
            $('#idpendiente').val(user_id);                           
            $('#operation').val("Edit");                
            $("#devolucion").attr({
                   "max" :10,                     
                });
           
        }
    })
});

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="devolucion" name="devolucion"  min="1" value="1" >
```

Estuve probando con la opción de atributos:

```
 $("#devolucion").attr({
               "max" :10,                     
            });
```

Pero no se como pasar el valor de val(data.cantidad) y colocarlo dentro del attr "max".

Comment: Funciono, Gracias, Si había probado colocar el data.cantidad pero le ponia punto y coma al final, y por eso no me funcionaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta agregando directamente `data.cantidad` en el atributo `max`... Algo como esto:

```
"max" : data.cantidad
```

sin la coma al final ya que solo estás pasando un atributo al método `attr`.

O puedes utilizar el método `prop` de `jQuery`

```
$("#devolucion").prop('max', data.cantidad);
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono, la opción PROP la desconocía, la probé y ambas funcionan!!!